"in" statement during declaration
I found this page. In the example the author uses in in the declaration and I'd like to know what it does:
let heap = Heap<Int> { l, r in
    l > r
}

I think it has something to do with object creation and somehow a Comparable is being set.
class Heap<T:Comparable> {
    typealias HeapComparator<T:Comparable> = (_ l:T,_ r:T) -> Bool

I can't seem to find the correct words to use as my search engine doesn't show appropriate hits. How is it called? What does it do? Where can I read more about it?
